# how to animate image using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want is when i click **hit-me** button, the image will move forward and get back to it's previous position. This will repeat again and again when i click the **hit-me** button.

Now, problem is when i click **hit-me** button the **image** move forward but it does not come back to it's previous position.

sorry for my bad english.

following is my **code**.

**boxing.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Employee Management System</title>
  <!-- Sets initial viewport load and disables zooming  -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ems.css">
  <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements. All other JS at the end of file. -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>

      <!--nav-->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Employee Management System</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Organization</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>


      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">Boxing</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <img class="ring" src="img/ring.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="hand" src="img/hand.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="center">
                  <button id="save-btn" class="game-btn btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <button id="hit-btn" class="game-btn btn btn-danger">Hit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/boxing.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**boxing.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hit-btn').on('click', function(){
        $('.hand').css({
            "-webkit-transform":"translateX(100px)",
            "-ms-transform":"translateX(100px)",
            "transform":"translateX(100px)"
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: can you please add your code in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try to take a look at this ?

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hit-btn').on('click', function(){
    $( ".hand" ).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" , function(){
      $( ".hand" ).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

try jquery animate.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link. Its exactly how you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/gt5d7/9/

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
   var sideMenu = false;
    $("#wel1").click(function() {
      if (!sideMenu) {

        sideMenu = true;
          $("#sidemenu").animate({
                "left": "300px"
            }, 3000);
      }
      else {
        $("#sidemenu").animate({left: "0px"}, 3000);

        sideMenu = false;     
      }
    });
});
```